# Evaluate in how many ways each cell on a board is under attack by the queens

Tags: algorithms

There's a board with given dimensions (NxM) and it has few queens places on some of the cells. We need to find in how many ways each cell is under attack by the queens on the board.
e.g.,

```
....Q
.Q..Q
.....
.....
```

Each empty cell is denoted by '.' and each cell having a queen placed is represented as 'Q'. For this configuration of board the answer is -

```
22221
11222
11111
02101
```

The problem has been stated in InterviewBit [Queen Attack](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/queen-attack/).

I solved this problem by listing down all the queens on the board and for each queen I traversed in all eight directions until either I reach the extremes of the board or find another queen while moving in a certain direction and incremented the attack counts for each cell on the way.

This solution didn't run in the expected time. The editorial solution does the counting for each direction for each cell and extends it to neighboring cells in that direction.

What I have not been able to understand is how the editorial solution has better running time that my solution. Can you try to find out for what cases my solution is slower than the editorial solution? Below are the links to the GitHub Gists of my solution and editorial solution -

[My Solution](https://gist.github.com/aakash-johari/183c694029b3a7099177ba2fc9486cab)
[Editorial Solution](https://gist.github.com/aakash-johari/0a8b20484d95bee62ec7cc5309738d36)

Comment: Code review is off-topic here. We are happy to help with any *algorithmic* issues.

Comment: Use a different programming language = factor 10 to 100. Turn optimisation on = factor 10. Write highly optimised code = factor 10. Big-O is not everything, constant factors can be important.